# where to specify libraries to link in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, configure

I'm sorry about the long text. But I want to compile the libxls library for C++. I've amended it to use ICU for handling encoding. Where in the following makefile can I add the respective library files to be linked to? NOTE, these libraries are named for ex. icudt.lib, so the notation -L, -l won't work. Also, ICU is setup with pkg-config, if that helps. And there are also a makefile.am and makefile.in, if they have any importance.

```
# Makefile.in generated by automake 1.13 from Makefile.am.
# Makefile.  Generated from Makefile.in by configure.

# Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

# This Makefile.in is free software; the Free Software Foundation
# gives unlimited permission to copy and/or distribute it,
# with or without modifications, as long as this notice is preserved.

# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law; without
# even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
# PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



am__make_dryrun = \
  { \
    am__dry=no; \
    case $$MAKEFLAGS in \
      *\\[\ \   ]*) \
        echo 'am--echo: ; @echo "AM"  OK' | $(MAKE) -f - 2>/dev/null \
          | grep '^AM OK$$' >/dev/null || am__dry=yes;; \
      *) \
        for am__flg in $$MAKEFLAGS; do \
          case $$am__flg in \
            *=*|--*) ;; \
            *n*) am__dry=yes; break;; \
          esac; \
        done;; \
    esac; \
    test $$am__dry = yes; \
  }
pkgdatadir = $(datadir)/libxls
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/libxls
pkglibdir = $(libdir)/libxls
pkglibexecdir = $(libexecdir)/libxls
am__cd = CDPATH="$${ZSH_VERSION+.}$(PATH_SEPARATOR)" && cd
install_sh_DATA = $(install_sh) -c -m 644
install_sh_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c
install_sh_SCRIPT = $(install_sh) -c
INSTALL_HEADER = $(INSTALL_DATA)
transform = $(program_transform_name)
NORMAL_INSTALL = :
PRE_INSTALL = :
POST_INSTALL = :
NORMAL_UNINSTALL = :
PRE_UNINSTALL = :
POST_UNINSTALL = :
build_triplet = i686-pc-mingw32
host_triplet = i686-pc-mingw32
subdir = .
DIST_COMMON = $(srcdir)/Makefile.in $(srcdir)/Makefile.am \
    $(top_srcdir)/configure $(am__configure_deps) \
    $(srcdir)/config.h.in mkinstalldirs AUTHORS INSTALL TODO \
    config.guess config.sub depcomp install-sh missing ltmain.sh
ACLOCAL_M4 = $(top_srcdir)/aclocal.m4
am__aclocal_m4_deps = $(top_srcdir)/m4/libtool.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltoptions.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltsugar.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/m4/ltversion.m4 $(top_srcdir)/m4/lt~obsolete.m4 \
    $(top_srcdir)/configure.in
am__configure_deps = $(am__aclocal_m4_deps) $(CONFIGURE_DEPENDENCIES) \
    $(ACLOCAL_M4)
am__CONFIG_DISTCLEAN_FILES = config.status config.cache config.log \
 configure.lineno config.status.lineno
mkinstalldirs = $(SHELL) $(top_srcdir)/mkinstalldirs
CONFIG_HEADER = config.h
CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES =
CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES =
AM_V_P = $(am__v_P_$(V))
am__v_P_ = $(am__v_P_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_P_0 = false
am__v_P_1 = :
AM_V_GEN = $(am__v_GEN_$(V))
am__v_GEN_ = $(am__v_GEN_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_GEN_0 = @echo "  GEN     " $@;
am__v_GEN_1 = 
AM_V_at = $(am__v_at_$(V))
am__v_at_ = $(am__v_at_$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY))
am__v_at_0 = @
am__v_at_1 = 
SOURCES =
DIST_SOURCES =
RECURSIVE_TARGETS = all-recursive check-recursive cscopelist-recursive \
    ctags-recursive dvi-recursive html-recursive info-recursive \
    install-data-recursive install-dvi-recursive \
    install-exec-recursive install-html-recursive \
    install-info-recursive install-pdf-recursive \
    install-ps-recursive install-recursive installcheck-recursive \
    installdirs-recursive pdf-recursive ps-recursive \
    tags-recursive uninstall-recursive
am__can_run_installinfo = \
  case $$AM_UPDATE_INFO_DIR in \
    n|no|NO) false;; \
    *) (install-info --version) >/dev/null 2>&1;; \
  esac
RECURSIVE_CLEAN_TARGETS = mostlyclean-recursive clean-recursive \
  distclean-recursive maintainer-clean-recursive
am__recursive_targets = \
  $(RECURSIVE_TARGETS) \
  $(RECURSIVE_CLEAN_TARGETS) \
  $(am__extra_recursive_targets)
AM_RECURSIVE_TARGETS = $(am__recursive_targets:-recursive=) TAGS CTAGS \
    cscope distdir dist dist-all distcheck
am__tagged_files = $(HEADERS) $(SOURCES) $(TAGS_FILES) \
    $(LISP)config.h.in
# Read a list of newline-separated strings from the standard input,
# and print each of them once, without duplicates.  Input order is
# *not* preserved.
am__uniquify_input = $(AWK) '\
  BEGIN { nonempty = 0; } \
  { items[$$0] = 1; nonempty = 1; } \
  END { if (nonempty) { for (i in items) print i; }; } \
'
# Make sure the list of sources is unique.  This is necessary because,
# e.g., the same source file might be shared among _SOURCES variables
# for different programs/libraries.
am__define_uniq_tagged_files = \
  list='$(am__tagged_files)'; \
  unique=`for i in $$list; do \
    if test -f "$$i"; then echo $$i; else echo $(srcdir)/$$i; fi; \
  done | $(am__uniquify_input)`
ETAGS = etags
CTAGS = ctags
CSCOPE = cscope
DIST_SUBDIRS = $(SUBDIRS)
DISTFILES = $(DIST_COMMON) $(DIST_SOURCES) $(TEXINFOS) $(EXTRA_DIST)
distdir = $(PACKAGE)-$(VERSION)
top_distdir = $(distdir)
am__remove_distdir = \
  if test -d "$(distdir)"; then \
    find "$(distdir)" -type d ! -perm -200 -exec chmod u+w {} ';' \
      && rm -rf "$(distdir)" \
      || { sleep 5 && rm -rf "$(distdir)"; }; \
  else :; fi
am__post_remove_distdir = $(am__remove_distdir)
am__relativize = \
  dir0=`pwd`; \
  sed_first='s,^\([^/]*\)/.*$$,\1,'; \
  sed_rest='s,^[^/]*/*,,'; \
  sed_last='s,^.*/\([^/]*\)$$,\1,'; \
  sed_butlast='s,/*[^/]*$$,,'; \
  while test -n "$$dir1"; do \
    first=`echo "$$dir1" | sed -e "$$sed_first"`; \
    if test "$$first" != "."; then \
      if test "$$first" = ".."; then \
        dir2=`echo "$$dir0" | sed -e "$$sed_last"`/"$$dir2"; \
        dir0=`echo "$$dir0" | sed -e "$$sed_butlast"`; \
      else \
        first2=`echo "$$dir2" | sed -e "$$sed_first"`; \
        if test "$$first2" = "$$first"; then \
          dir2=`echo "$$dir2" | sed -e "$$sed_rest"`; \
        else \
          dir2="../$$dir2"; \
        fi; \
        dir0="$$dir0"/"$$first"; \
      fi; \
    fi; \
    dir1=`echo "$$dir1" | sed -e "$$sed_rest"`; \
  done; \
  reldir="$$dir2"
DIST_ARCHIVES = $(distdir).tar.gz $(distdir).zip
GZIP_ENV = --best
DIST_TARGETS = dist-gzip dist-zip
distuninstallcheck_listfiles = find . -type f -print
am__distuninstallcheck_listfiles = $(distuninstallcheck_listfiles) \
  | sed 's|^\./|$(prefix)/|' | grep -v '$(infodir)/dir$$'
distcleancheck_listfiles = find . -type f -print
ACLOCAL = ${SHELL} /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4/missing aclocal-1.13
AMTAR = $${TAR-tar}
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY = 1
AR = ar
AUTOCONF = ${SHELL} /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4/missing autoconf
AUTOHEADER = ${SHELL} /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4/missing autoheader
AUTOMAKE = ${SHELL} /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4/missing automake-1.13
AWK = gawk
CC = gcc -std=gnu99
CCDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CFLAGS = -g -O2
CPP = gcc -E
CPPFLAGS = 
CXX = g++
CXXCPP = g++ -E
CXXDEPMODE = depmode=gcc3
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
CYGPATH_W = echo
DEFS = -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DEPDIR = .deps
DSYMUTIL = 
DUMPBIN = 
ECHO_C = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_T = 
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
EXEEXT = .exe
FGREP = /bin/grep -F
GREP = /bin/grep
INSTALL = /bin/install -c
INSTALL_DATA = ${INSTALL} -m 644
INSTALL_PROGRAM = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_SCRIPT = ${INSTALL}
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM = $(install_sh) -c -s
LD = c:/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe
LDFLAGS = 
LIBOBJS = 
LIBS = /mingw/lib/icuin.lib /mingw/lib/icuuc.lib /mingw/lib/icudt.lib
LIBTOOL = $(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool
LIBTOOL_DEPS = ./ltmain.sh
LIBXLS_LIBS =  /mingw/lib/icuin.lib /mingw/lib/icuuc.lib /mingw/lib/icudt.lib
LIBXLS_MAJOR_VERSION = 1
LIBXLS_MICRO_VERSION = 1
LIBXLS_MINOR_VERSION = 2
LIPO = 
LN_S = cp -pR
LTLIBOBJS = 
MAKEINFO = ${SHELL} /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4/missing makeinfo
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
NM = /mingw/bin/nm
NMEDIT = 
OBJDUMP = objdump
OBJEXT = o
OTOOL = 
OTOOL64 = 
PACKAGE = libxls
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = dhoerl@users.sourceforge.net
PACKAGE_NAME = libxls
PACKAGE_STRING = libxls 1.2.1
PACKAGE_TARNAME = libxls
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 1.2.1
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
PKG_CONFIG = /mingw/bin/pkg-config
RANLIB = ranlib
SED = /bin/sed
SET_MAKE = 
SHELL = /bin/sh
STRIP = strip
VERSION = 1.2.1
VERSION_INFO = 3:1:2
WITH_ICONV = 0
abs_builddir = /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4
abs_srcdir = /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4
abs_top_builddir = /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4
abs_top_srcdir = /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4
ac_ct_CC = gcc
ac_ct_CXX = g++
ac_ct_DUMPBIN = 
am__include = include
am__leading_dot = .
am__quote = 
am__tar = $${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"
am__untar = $${TAR-tar} xf -
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
build = i686-pc-mingw32
build_alias = 
build_cpu = i686
build_os = mingw32
build_vendor = pc
builddir = .
datadir = ${datarootdir}
datarootdir = ${prefix}/share
docdir = ${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}
dvidir = ${docdir}
exec_prefix = ${prefix}
host = i686-pc-mingw32
host_alias = 
host_cpu = i686
host_os = mingw32
host_vendor = pc
htmldir = ${docdir}
includedir = ${prefix}/include
infodir = ${datarootdir}/info
install_sh = ${SHELL} /c/Users/sirghi/Desktop/libxls-1.3.4/install-sh
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
libexecdir = ${exec_prefix}/libexec
localedir = ${datarootdir}/locale
localstatedir = ${prefix}/var
mandir = ${datarootdir}/man
mkdir_p = $(MKDIR_P)
oldincludedir = /usr/include
pdfdir = ${docdir}
prefix = /mingw
program_transform_name = s,x,x,
psdir = ${docdir}
sbindir = ${exec_prefix}/sbin
sharedstatedir = ${prefix}/com
srcdir = .
sysconfdir = ${prefix}/etc
target_alias = 
top_build_prefix = 
top_builddir = .
top_srcdir = .
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign dist-zip
SUBDIRS = include src test 
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS}

# Extra files to distribute
EXTRA_DIST = doc
all: config.h
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-recursive

.SUFFIXES:
am--refresh: Makefile
    @:
$(srcdir)/Makefile.in:  $(srcdir)/Makefile.am  $(am__configure_deps)
    @for dep in $?; do \
      case '$(am__configure_deps)' in \
        *$$dep*) \
          echo ' cd $(srcdir) && $(AUTOMAKE) --foreign'; \
          $(am__cd) $(srcdir) && $(AUTOMAKE) --foreign \
        && exit 0; \
          exit 1;; \
      esac; \
    done; \
    echo ' cd $(top_srcdir) && $(AUTOMAKE) --foreign Makefile'; \
    $(am__cd) $(top_srcdir) && \
      $(AUTOMAKE) --foreign Makefile
.PRECIOUS: Makefile
Makefile: $(srcdir)/Makefile.in $(top_builddir)/config.status
    @case '$?' in \
      *config.status*) \
        echo ' $(SHELL) ./config.status'; \
        $(SHELL) ./config.status;; \
      *) \
        echo ' cd $(top_builddir) && $(SHELL) ./config.status $@ $(am__depfiles_maybe)'; \
        cd $(top_builddir) && $(SHELL) ./config.status $@ $(am__depfiles_maybe);; \
    esac;

$(top_builddir)/config.status: $(top_srcdir)/configure $(CONFIG_STATUS_DEPENDENCIES)
    $(SHELL) ./config.status --recheck

$(top_srcdir)/configure:  $(am__configure_deps)
    $(am__cd) $(srcdir) && $(AUTOCONF)
$(ACLOCAL_M4):  $(am__aclocal_m4_deps)
    $(am__cd) $(srcdir) && $(ACLOCAL) $(ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS)
$(am__aclocal_m4_deps):

config.h: stamp-h1
    @if test ! -f $@; then rm -f stamp-h1; else :; fi
    @if test ! -f $@; then $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) stamp-h1; else :; fi

stamp-h1: $(srcdir)/config.h.in $(top_builddir)/config.status
    @rm -f stamp-h1
    cd $(top_builddir) && $(SHELL) ./config.status config.h
$(srcdir)/config.h.in:  $(am__configure_deps) 
    ($(am__cd) $(top_srcdir) && $(AUTOHEADER))
    rm -f stamp-h1
    touch $@

distclean-hdr:
    -rm -f config.h stamp-h1

mostlyclean-libtool:
    -rm -f *.lo

clean-libtool:
    -rm -rf .libs _libs

distclean-libtool:
    -rm -f libtool config.lt

# This directory's subdirectories are mostly independent; you can cd
# into them and run 'make' without going through this Makefile.
# To change the values of 'make' variables: instead of editing Makefiles,
# (1) if the variable is set in 'config.status', edit 'config.status'
#     (which will cause the Makefiles to be regenerated when you run 'make');
# (2) otherwise, pass the desired values on the 'make' command line.
$(am__recursive_targets):
    @fail= failcom='exit 1'; \
    for f in x $$MAKEFLAGS; do \
      case $$f in \
        *=* | --[!k]*);; \
        *k*) failcom='fail=yes';; \
      esac; \
    done; \
    dot_seen=no; \
    target=`echo $@ | sed s/-recursive//`; \
    case "$@" in \
      distclean-* | maintainer-clean-*) list='$(DIST_SUBDIRS)' ;; \
      *) list='$(SUBDIRS)' ;; \
    esac; \
    for subdir in $$list; do \
      echo "Making $$target in $$subdir"; \
      if test "$$subdir" = "."; then \
        dot_seen=yes; \
        local_target="$$target-am"; \
      else \
        local_target="$$target"; \
      fi; \
      ($(am__cd) $$subdir && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $$local_target) \
      || eval $$failcom; \
    done; \
    if test "$$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) "$$target-am" || exit 1; \
    fi; test -z "$$fail"

ID: $(am__tagged_files)
    $(am__define_uniq_tagged_files); mkid -fID $$unique
tags: tags-recursive
TAGS: tags

tags-am: $(TAGS_DEPENDENCIES) $(am__tagged_files)
    set x; \
    here=`pwd`; \
    if ($(ETAGS) --etags-include --version) >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
      include_option=--etags-include; \
      empty_fix=.; \
    else \
      include_option=--include; \
      empty_fix=; \
    fi; \
    list='$(SUBDIRS)'; for subdir in $$list; do \
      if test "$$subdir" = .; then :; else \
        test ! -f $$subdir/TAGS || \
          set "$$@" "$$include_option=$$here/$$subdir/TAGS"; \
      fi; \
    done; \
    $(am__define_uniq_tagged_files); \
    shift; \
    if test -z "$(ETAGS_ARGS)$$*$$unique"; then :; else \
      test -n "$$unique" || unique=$$empty_fix; \
      if test $$# -gt 0; then \
        $(ETAGS) $(ETAGSFLAGS) $(AM_ETAGSFLAGS) $(ETAGS_ARGS) \
          "$$@" $$unique; \
      else \
        $(ETAGS) $(ETAGSFLAGS) $(AM_ETAGSFLAGS) $(ETAGS_ARGS) \
          $$unique; \
      fi; \
    fi
ctags: ctags-recursive

CTAGS: ctags
ctags-am: $(TAGS_DEPENDENCIES) $(am__tagged_files)
    $(am__define_uniq_tagged_files); \
    test -z "$(CTAGS_ARGS)$$unique" \
      || $(CTAGS) $(CTAGSFLAGS) $(AM_CTAGSFLAGS) $(CTAGS_ARGS) \
         $$unique

GTAGS:
    here=`$(am__cd) $(top_builddir) && pwd` \
      && $(am__cd) $(top_srcdir) \
      && gtags -i $(GTAGS_ARGS) "$$here"
cscope: cscope.files
    test ! -s cscope.files \
      || $(CSCOPE) -b -q $(AM_CSCOPEFLAGS) $(CSCOPEFLAGS) -i cscope.files $(CSCOPE_ARGS)
clean-cscope:
    -rm -f cscope.files
cscope.files: clean-cscope cscopelist
cscopelist: cscopelist-recursive

cscopelist-am: $(am__tagged_files)
    list='$(am__tagged_files)'; \
    case "$(srcdir)" in \
      [\\/]* | ?:[\\/]*) sdir="$(srcdir)" ;; \
      *) sdir=$(subdir)/$(srcdir) ;; \
    esac; \
    for i in $$list; do \
      if test -f "$$i"; then \
        echo "$(subdir)/$$i"; \
      else \
        echo "$$sdir/$$i"; \
      fi; \
    done >> $(top_builddir)/cscope.files

distclean-tags:
    -rm -f TAGS ID GTAGS GRTAGS GSYMS GPATH tags
    -rm -f cscope.out cscope.in.out cscope.po.out cscope.files

distdir: $(DISTFILES)
    $(am__remove_distdir)
    test -d "$(distdir)" || mkdir "$(distdir)"
    @srcdirstrip=`echo "$(srcdir)" | sed 's/[].[^$$\\*]/\\\\&/g'`; \
    topsrcdirstrip=`echo "$(top_srcdir)" | sed 's/[].[^$$\\*]/\\\\&/g'`; \
    list='$(DISTFILES)'; \
      dist_files=`for file in $$list; do echo $$file; done | \
      sed -e "s|^$$srcdirstrip/||;t" \
          -e "s|^$$topsrcdirstrip/|$(top_builddir)/|;t"`; \
    case $$dist_files in \
      */*) $(MKDIR_P) `echo "$$dist_files" | \
               sed '/\//!d;s|^|$(distdir)/|;s,/[^/]*$$,,' | \
               sort -u` ;; \
    esac; \
    for file in $$dist_files; do \
      if test -f $$file || test -d $$file; then d=.; else d=$(srcdir); fi; \
      if test -d $$d/$$file; then \
        dir=`echo "/$$file" | sed -e 's,/[^/]*$$,,'`; \
        if test -d "$(distdir)/$$file"; then \
          find "$(distdir)/$$file" -type d ! -perm -700 -exec chmod u+rwx {} \;; \
        fi; \
        if test -d $(srcdir)/$$file && test $$d != $(srcdir); then \
          cp -fpR $(srcdir)/$$file "$(distdir)$$dir" || exit 1; \
          find "$(distdir)/$$file" -type d ! -perm -700 -exec chmod u+rwx {} \;; \
        fi; \
        cp -fpR $$d/$$file "$(distdir)$$dir" || exit 1; \
      else \
        test -f "$(distdir)/$$file" \
        || cp -p $$d/$$file "$(distdir)/$$file" \
        || exit 1; \
      fi; \
    done
    @list='$(DIST_SUBDIRS)'; for subdir in $$list; do \
      if test "$$subdir" = .; then :; else \
        $(am__make_dryrun) \
          || test -d "$(distdir)/$$subdir" \
          || $(MKDIR_P) "$(distdir)/$$subdir" \
          || exit 1; \
        dir1=$$subdir; dir2="$(distdir)/$$subdir"; \
        $(am__relativize); \
        new_distdir=$$reldir; \
        dir1=$$subdir; dir2="$(top_distdir)"; \
        $(am__relativize); \
        new_top_distdir=$$reldir; \
        echo " (cd $$subdir && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) top_distdir="$$new_top_distdir" distdir="$$new_distdir" \\"; \
        echo "     am__remove_distdir=: am__skip_length_check=: am__skip_mode_fix=: distdir)"; \
        ($(am__cd) $$subdir && \
          $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) \
            top_distdir="$$new_top_distdir" \
            distdir="$$new_distdir" \
        am__remove_distdir=: \
        am__skip_length_check=: \
        am__skip_mode_fix=: \
            distdir) \
          || exit 1; \
      fi; \
    done
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) \
      top_distdir="$(top_distdir)" distdir="$(distdir)" \
      dist-hook
    -test -n "$(am__skip_mode_fix)" \
    || find "$(distdir)" -type d ! -perm -755 \
        -exec chmod u+rwx,go+rx {} \; -o \
      ! -type d ! -perm -444 -links 1 -exec chmod a+r {} \; -o \
      ! -type d ! -perm -400 -exec chmod a+r {} \; -o \
      ! -type d ! -perm -444 -exec $(install_sh) -c -m a+r {} {} \; \
    || chmod -R a+r "$(distdir)"
dist-gzip: distdir
    tardir=$(distdir) && $(am__tar) | GZIP=$(GZIP_ENV) gzip -c >$(distdir).tar.gz
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

dist-bzip2: distdir
    tardir=$(distdir) && $(am__tar) | BZIP2=$${BZIP2--9} bzip2 -c >$(distdir).tar.bz2
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

dist-lzip: distdir
    tardir=$(distdir) && $(am__tar) | lzip -c $${LZIP_OPT--9} >$(distdir).tar.lz
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

dist-xz: distdir
    tardir=$(distdir) && $(am__tar) | XZ_OPT=$${XZ_OPT--e} xz -c >$(distdir).tar.xz
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

dist-tarZ: distdir
    tardir=$(distdir) && $(am__tar) | compress -c >$(distdir).tar.Z
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

dist-shar: distdir
    shar $(distdir) | GZIP=$(GZIP_ENV) gzip -c >$(distdir).shar.gz
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)
dist-zip: distdir
    -rm -f $(distdir).zip
    zip -rq $(distdir).zip $(distdir)
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

dist dist-all:
    $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) $(DIST_TARGETS) am__post_remove_distdir='@:'
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)

# This target untars the dist file and tries a VPATH configuration.  Then
# it guarantees that the distribution is self-contained by making another
# tarfile.
distcheck: dist
    case '$(DIST_ARCHIVES)' in \
    *.tar.gz*) \
      GZIP=$(GZIP_ENV) gzip -dc $(distdir).tar.gz | $(am__untar) ;;\
    *.tar.bz2*) \
      bzip2 -dc $(distdir).tar.bz2 | $(am__untar) ;;\
    *.tar.lz*) \
      lzip -dc $(distdir).tar.lz | $(am__untar) ;;\
    *.tar.xz*) \
      xz -dc $(distdir).tar.xz | $(am__untar) ;;\
    *.tar.Z*) \
      uncompress -c $(distdir).tar.Z | $(am__untar) ;;\
    *.shar.gz*) \
      GZIP=$(GZIP_ENV) gzip -dc $(distdir).shar.gz | unshar ;;\
    *.zip*) \
      unzip $(distdir).zip ;;\
    esac
    chmod -R a-w $(distdir)
    chmod u+w $(distdir)
    mkdir $(distdir)/_build $(distdir)/_inst
    chmod a-w $(distdir)
    test -d $(distdir)/_build || exit 0; \
    dc_install_base=`$(am__cd) $(distdir)/_inst && pwd | sed -e 's,^[^:\\/]:[\\/],/,'` \
      && dc_destdir="$${TMPDIR-/tmp}/am-dc-$$$$/" \
      && am__cwd=`pwd` \
      && $(am__cd) $(distdir)/_build \
      && ../configure --srcdir=.. --prefix="$$dc_install_base" \
        $(AM_DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS) \
        $(DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS) \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) dvi \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) check \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) installcheck \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) uninstall \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) distuninstallcheck_dir="$$dc_install_base" \
            distuninstallcheck \
      && chmod -R a-w "$$dc_install_base" \
      && ({ \
           (cd ../.. && umask 077 && mkdir "$$dc_destdir") \
           && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" install \
           && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" uninstall \
           && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) DESTDIR="$$dc_destdir" \
                distuninstallcheck_dir="$$dc_destdir" distuninstallcheck; \
          } || { rm -rf "$$dc_destdir"; exit 1; }) \
      && rm -rf "$$dc_destdir" \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) dist \
      && rm -rf $(DIST_ARCHIVES) \
      && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) distcleancheck \
      && cd "$$am__cwd" \
      || exit 1
    $(am__post_remove_distdir)
    @(echo "$(distdir) archives ready for distribution: "; \
      list='$(DIST_ARCHIVES)'; for i in $$list; do echo $$i; done) | \
      sed -e 1h -e 1s/./=/g -e 1p -e 1x -e '$$p' -e '$$x'
distuninstallcheck:
    @test -n '$(distuninstallcheck_dir)' || { \
      echo 'ERROR: trying to run $@ with an empty' \
           '$$(distuninstallcheck_dir)' >&2; \
      exit 1; \
    }; \
    $(am__cd) '$(distuninstallcheck_dir)' || { \
      echo 'ERROR: cannot chdir into $(distuninstallcheck_dir)' >&2; \
      exit 1; \
    }; \
    test `$(am__distuninstallcheck_listfiles) | wc -l` -eq 0 \
       || { echo "ERROR: files left after uninstall:" ; \
            if test -n "$(DESTDIR)"; then \
              echo "  (check DESTDIR support)"; \
            fi ; \
            $(distuninstallcheck_listfiles) ; \
            exit 1; } >&2
distcleancheck: distclean
    @if test '$(srcdir)' = . ; then \
      echo "ERROR: distcleancheck can only run from a VPATH build" ; \
      exit 1 ; \
    fi
    @test `$(distcleancheck_listfiles) | wc -l` -eq 0 \
      || { echo "ERROR: files left in build directory after distclean:" ; \
           $(distcleancheck_listfiles) ; \
           exit 1; } >&2
check-am: all-am
check: check-recursive
all-am: Makefile config.h
installdirs: installdirs-recursive
installdirs-am:
install: install-recursive
install-exec: install-exec-recursive
install-data: install-data-recursive
uninstall: uninstall-recursive

install-am: all-am
    @$(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) install-exec-am install-data-am

installcheck: installcheck-recursive
install-strip:
    if test -z '$(STRIP)'; then \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
        install_sh_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" INSTALL_STRIP_FLAG=-s \
          install; \
    else \
      $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) INSTALL_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" \
        install_sh_PROGRAM="$(INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM)" INSTALL_STRIP_FLAG=-s \
        "INSTALL_PROGRAM_ENV=STRIPPROG='$(STRIP)'" install; \
    fi
mostlyclean-generic:

clean-generic:

distclean-generic:
    -test -z "$(CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES)" || rm -f $(CONFIG_CLEAN_FILES)
    -test . = "$(srcdir)" || test -z "$(CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES)" || rm -f $(CONFIG_CLEAN_VPATH_FILES)

maintainer-clean-generic:
    @echo "This command is intended for maintainers to use"
    @echo "it deletes files that may require special tools to rebuild."
clean: clean-recursive

clean-am: clean-generic clean-libtool mostlyclean-am

distclean: distclean-recursive
    -rm -f $(am__CONFIG_DISTCLEAN_FILES)
    -rm -f Makefile
distclean-am: clean-am distclean-generic distclean-hdr \
    distclean-libtool distclean-tags

dvi: dvi-recursive

dvi-am:

html: html-recursive

html-am:

info: info-recursive

info-am:

install-data-am:

install-dvi: install-dvi-recursive

install-dvi-am:

install-exec-am:

install-html: install-html-recursive

install-html-am:

install-info: install-info-recursive

install-info-am:

install-man:

install-pdf: install-pdf-recursive

install-pdf-am:

install-ps: install-ps-recursive

install-ps-am:

installcheck-am:

maintainer-clean: maintainer-clean-recursive
    -rm -f $(am__CONFIG_DISTCLEAN_FILES)
    -rm -rf $(top_srcdir)/autom4te.cache
    -rm -f Makefile
maintainer-clean-am: distclean-am maintainer-clean-generic

mostlyclean: mostlyclean-recursive

mostlyclean-am: mostlyclean-generic mostlyclean-libtool

pdf: pdf-recursive

pdf-am:

ps: ps-recursive

ps-am:

uninstall-am:

.MAKE: $(am__recursive_targets) all install-am install-strip

.PHONY: $(am__recursive_targets) CTAGS GTAGS TAGS all all-am \
    am--refresh check check-am clean clean-cscope clean-generic \
    clean-libtool cscope cscopelist-am ctags ctags-am dist \
    dist-all dist-bzip2 dist-gzip dist-hook dist-lzip dist-shar \
    dist-tarZ dist-xz dist-zip distcheck distclean \
    distclean-generic distclean-hdr distclean-libtool \
    distclean-tags distcleancheck distdir distuninstallcheck dvi \
    dvi-am html html-am info info-am install install-am \
    install-data install-data-am install-dvi install-dvi-am \
    install-exec install-exec-am install-html install-html-am \
    install-info install-info-am install-man install-pdf \
    install-pdf-am install-ps install-ps-am install-strip \
    installcheck installcheck-am installdirs installdirs-am \
    maintainer-clean maintainer-clean-generic mostlyclean \
    mostlyclean-generic mostlyclean-libtool pdf pdf-am ps ps-am \
    tags tags-am uninstall uninstall-am


dist-hook:
    rm -rf `find $(distdir)/doc -name CVS`

# Tell versions [3.59,3.63) of GNU make to not export all variables.
# Otherwise a system limit (for SysV at least) may be exceeded.
.NOEXPORT:
```

As you can see, I tried setting the LIBS variable:

```
LIBS = /mingw/lib/icuin.lib /mingw/lib/icuuc.lib /mingw/lib/icudt.lib
```

but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Comment: @IuriCovalisin the error is that there are some functions (defined in these libraries) that give an "undefined reference to function XXX()" error.

Comment: @lolando, where is the resulting command displayed? I've written that the libraries don't follow the _lib**.a_ pattern, instead they are _***.lib_, so I can't use the -L -l notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've found:

```
# The following naming scheme is used for libraries.
#
# On *nix:
#     libxxx.a       static library
#     libxxx.so      shared library
#
# On windows (msvc)
#     libxxx.lib     static library
#     xxx.dll        DLL
#     xxx.lib        import library
#
# On windows (mingw):
#     libxxx.a       static library
#     libxxx.dll     DLL
#     libxxx.dll.a   import library
#
# On cygwin i.e. <target-os>cygwin
#     libxxx.a       static library
#     cygxxx.dll     DLL
#     libxxx.dll.a   import library
```

It appears *gcc* detects all of these types on my windows. So, it finally worked with the -lxxx notation, but I used it as an argument to the **configure** script. I still don't know where I can put them manually in the **makefile**. I've searched the generated **makefiles** for the libraries but couldn't find them. Don't know where *automake* has put them.